# Set Up IP in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: networking, connection, ip, 12.04

I am trying to set IP's for a Wired connection in Ubuntu via the **Network Connections** GUI. However, In wired connections, when I select Manual IPv4 settings the **"SAVE"** button get greyed out and I can't update the new changes. (IP, Gateway, subnet and DNS)..

I have googled extensively and tried all the suggestions given. However it does not seem to work whatsoever. I have tried changing the  **/etc/network/interfaces** file to set static ip for ethernet interface. Still it does not work. I get the set IP details for the ethernet interface when I try - ***ifconfig /all***. However I cant connect to the internet.

Can someone please help me to get this right....

Comment: Can you connect when it's automatic?

Comment: No I cannot even connect when its automatic.....

Comment: Have you filled in all 3 boxes with the details? - see http://goo.gl/xzfYzw

Comment: Yes I did... The "save" button gets greyed out as soon as I select manual. Also in this site: 

http://www.sudo-juice.com/how-to-set-a-static-ip-in-ubuntu-the-proper-way/

the author says: To regain control of our network interfaces we first have to disable nm-tools’ management of them. 

Should I try that also?? I haven't tried this bcz I am out of my University Lab where I need to connect via the ethernet

Comment: Try http://www.howtogeek.com/?p=169, it's what I used to get it working.

Comment: Will try it when I get to the University...
Thanks Very Much..
Il try that and reply.. I can only try in about 10 hours

Comment: That's fine. Between 4pm and 10pm, I'm almost always watching out for messages.

Comment: I tried as explained in the link above. Still it does not work. After making all the changes and restarting network services: I tried **ifconfig -a** and it prints the IP details as set for **eth0**. But I can't get to the internet!!!!

Comment: Do you have a second computer on the LAN? If so, can you access that one's public files, and vice versa?

Comment: No. Its the lab network at my University where each machine is set with a static IP. Im trying to use this ethernet connection to connect to the internet by plugging the cable from one PC in the lab into my Laptop. I can set settings and connect in Windows but can't do so in Ubuntu...

Comment: What is the ip of the computer you're unplugging it from?

Comment: The same as that I gave: 10.22.40.01

Comment: Does the university block Ubuntu? As it works in Windows, that may be the problem? Can people connect macs, and have others used ubuntu?

Comment: Well there are other friends who use Arch Linux and stuff. It can't be so. Also why is the **SAVE** button greyed out when I select Manual in the Networks COnfigurations GUI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried searching in the internet extensively and also many different suggestions but none of them worked. However I got it checked by one of friends. He tried many stuff on his own too but did not work initially.

Later he tried using **24** for the netmask (instead of the common 255.255.255.0) in the the **Network Configurations** window and then **BINGO** the Save button got enabled again and then I could save the settings. Now the usual "255.255.255.0" also works fine.

Following this I restarted the service using **sudo service network-manager restart** and now all is working fine!!!!

Thanks Tim and everyone